# Why does my wp_safe_redirect output the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error?

Tags: actions, wp-redirect

I've built a demo page and now I'd like to redirect on it whenever an user logs in and hasn't set up his theme, my code being:

```
function add_admin_page()
{
    if ( empty( $_GET['page'] ) || $_GET['page'] !== 'theme_setup' ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ob_get_length() ) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div> Hey, this is the awesome back-end page.</div>

    <?php
    exit;
}


function add_admin_menu() {

    $page = add_theme_page(
        'Theme Setup', 'Theme Setup', 'manage_options', 'theme_setup', 'add_admin_page'
    );
}

add_admin_menu();
```

And the redirect:

```
function redirect() {
    wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( 'themes.php?page=theme_setup' ) );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'init', 'redirect' );
```

But this generates the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Thing is, I plan on pulling data from other plugins that only load in the back-end, what would be a good hook for me to redirect the user and still catch hooks like `init` and `admin_init`?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're in an infinite loop.

When the user visits the site, `init` fires, and they get redirected to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

Then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

So then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

So then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

So then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

So then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

So then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

So then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

So then they arrive on `themes.php?page=theme_setup` and the `init` hook fires and redirects them to `themes.php?page=theme_setup`

.......

The browser, seeing that this keeps happening, has been counting, and when it reaches a threshold, it intervenes, and says NO, you're looping and it will never end, I'm serving you a warning ( titled `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` )

So there are a number of problems:

- UX: Why are you kidnapping the user and sending them there instead of prompting the user to visit themselves? The poor user will be dazed and confused because they expect to be in one place, but have been wrenched from that location and put somewhere else. It's incredibly confusing. Stop that, it's not nice
- Checks and infinite loops: You never check if the user is already on that page, or if a redirect has occurred already. Additionally, if saving that page involves visiting any other page then it won't save and you're back to square one
- Auth: Because it's on the `init` hook, it will fire even for logged out users. That code would make the site unviewable as visitors would be redirected to WP Admin which would try to redirect to the login page, triggering your code, leading to more infinite loops
- Compatibility: Clicking activate is not the only way to activate a theme. E.g. what happens if a user uses the WP.com calypso interface to activate the theme? Or WP CLI? Or clicks live preview instead of activate and does it via the customizer? In all those situations, either a REST API call will be redirected, an AJAX call, or there's no browser to redirect. A redirection in all this cases will either result in no redirection, or break it entirely
- Live Preview Issues: Previewing the theme via the customizer would lead the preview pane towards the settings page, making the theme impossible to preview

So, instead, I recommend that you prompt the user by prompting them, not redirecting them. Do this by adding a banner to the admin area like most themes and plugins do, or a modal dialog. Set up good sane defaults too, and don't do it on the frontend, admin only, and check if the user is logged in and has the ability to set those settings. You don't want to give a subscriber role the prompt or access to settings.

Redirects like this are bad, hostile, and break things. If you want to prompt the user, **just prompt them**

Comment: The goal here is to, when people activate my theme to prompt them with this setup page, if not, they can leave.

Comment: nifty but given the number of ways you can activate a theme, it might not work how you expect it to, and there's a difference between prompting a user and forcibly redirecting them. E.g what happens if a user activates a theme via a live preview in the customizer, it'll be an AJAX call that gets redirected, and the activation will fail.

Comment: Instead, detect if the user has ran the setup, and prompt them with an actual prompt, be it a banner or a modal dialog that they can dismiss. Using `wp_redirect` is user hostile and fraught with problems